# Keep checkbox checked after form submit. Custom post type, WordPress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm making my own custom post type where I'm currently displaying all images from the gallery with a checkbox for each image. I want the user to be able to be able to check the checkbox for the image that he/she wants to display on the post. This part works. The problem is that the checkbox is unchecked after the form has been submitted. How do I keep it checked?

```
function po_product_image_html($post) {

echo '<div style="width: 80px; display: inline-block;">';

    $imgs = get_media_library_images();

    foreach ($imgs as $img)
    {
        echo '<img style="height: 80px; width: 80px; padding: 10px;" src="'.$img.'" />';
        echo '<input name="product_image[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$img.'" />';
    }           

echo '</div>';
```

}

The function for saving the form.

```
function po_products_save_postdata() {

global $post;

update_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_desc', $_POST['product_desc']);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_url', $_POST['product_url']);
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_image', $_POST['product_image']);

}

add_action('save_post', 'po_products_save_postdata');
```

The function for getting the images from media library used in the first code snippet.

```
function get_media_library_images()
{
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$query_images = new WP_Query($args);

$images = array();

foreach ($query_images->posts as $image)
{
    $images[] = $image->guid;
}

return $images;
}
```

I've tried the `isset($_POST['product_image'])` thingy to `echo checked="checked"` in the checkbox, but no luck so far. Is the problem that `$_POST['product_image']` is an array?

Best regards, Mac.

Comment: is it 1 image you check per post ?

Comment: Also what are you passing in your po_product_image_html($post) as argument? Is it the current post id ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it this way:

```
echo '<div>';

global $post;

$imgs = get_media_library_images();
$post_selected_images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'product_image', true);

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    <input name="product_image[]" type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array($img, $post_selected_images)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="<?php echo $img ?>" />
    <?php
    echo '</div>';
}           

echo '</div>';
```

If the value of the $img variable is stored in the $post_selected_images array I simply echo 'checked="checked"' in the input element.